# footnotemark equivalent for tablefootnote - to reference/use the same footnote multiple times

Tags: tables, footnotes

There is an option to mark the same cross reference in footnote using footnotemark.

Can I do the same for tablefootnote?

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
This is the first line........\tablefootnote{according to amitha}\\
This is second line where I have same footnote \tablefootnote{according to amitha}
\end{tabular}

Here for footnote\footnote{\label{mark}Here its working fine}, here is an optiion
\footnotemark[\ref{mark}].


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Before the answer**, let me explain you why your MWE will never work.  According to page 3 of the `tablefootnote` documentation [(tablefootnote.pdf)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tablefootnote/tablefootnote.pdf):

> If \tablefootnote{...} is used in a tabular environment, which is
>   inside of a (sideways)table environment, everything is fine, but when
>   the tabular environment is not inside of a (sideways)table, the
>   tablefootnote will not work.

---

As far as I could find, there is no direct equivalent to `\footnote`-`\footnotemark[...]` using the `tablefootnote` package.  You can, however, simulate it.  First, I provide the direct approach and second, is a command shortcut.  (Images cropped to reduce space)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

First footnote\footnote{\label{mark1}First standard footnote}, 
here is another reference to the first standard footnote \footnotemark[\getrefnumber{mark1}].

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \hline
    This is the 
    first line........\tablefootnote{first table footnote\label{reference footnote}} \\
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    This is second line where I have 
    same first table footnote \textsuperscript{\getrefnumber{reference footnote}} \\
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    This is the 
    third line........\tablefootnote{second table footnote\label{reference footnote two}} \\
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    This is fourth line where I have 
    same second table footnote \textsuperscript{\getrefnumber{reference footnote two}} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Last footnote\footnote{\label{mark2}Second standard footnote}, 
here is another reference to the second standard footnote \footnotemark[\getrefnumber{mark2}].

\end{document}
```

[image: Version one of referencing existing tablefootnote]

Second way, with a command shortcut:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{refcount}

\def\tablefootnotemark#1{\textsuperscript{\getrefnumber{#1}}}
%If you prefer \newcommand then use this one
%\newcommand{\tablefootnotemark}[1]{\textsuperscript{\getrefnumber{#1}}}

\begin{document}

First footnote\footnote{\label{mark1}First standard footnote}, 
here is another reference to the first standard footnote \footnotemark[\getrefnumber{mark1}].

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \hline
    This is the 
    first line........\tablefootnote{first table footnote\label{example tablefootnote one}} \\
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    This is second line where I have 
    same first table footnote \tablefootnotemark{example tablefootnote one} \\
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    This is the 
    third line........\tablefootnote{second table footnote\label{example tablefootnote two}} \\
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    This is fourth line where I have 
    same second table footnote \tablefootnotemark{example tablefootnote two} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Last footnote\footnote{\label{mark2}Second standard footnote}, 
here is another reference to the second standard footnote \footnotemark[\getrefnumber{mark2}].

\end{document}
```

[image: Version two of referencing existing tablefootnote]

I included a second version using `\newcommand`, in case you have a preference.  You could make a similar command shortcut for `\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{...}]`, of course.